# counting foreach loop items

Tags: php, foreach

i have the following array:

```
[2]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (4) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(32) "43c845f895a56fbe8aea9435ef8fa806"
    ["Type"]=>
    string(8) "Campaign"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(28) "An unmissable invitation for"
    ["Actions"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#10 (4) {
        ["Event"]=>
        string(4) "Open"
        ["Date"]=>
        string(19) "2013-05-07 17:00:00"
        ["IPAddress"]=>
        string(12) "109.239.93.2"
        ["Detail"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#11 (4) {
        ["Event"]=>
        string(4) "Open"
        ["Date"]=>
        string(19) "2013-05-07 09:01:00"
        ["IPAddress"]=>
        string(12) "109.239.93.2"
        ["Detail"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#12 (4) {
        ["Event"]=>
        string(4) "Open"
        ["Date"]=>
        string(19) "2013-04-30 22:29:00"
        ["IPAddress"]=>
        string(14) "94.171.192.216"
        ["Detail"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#13 (4) {
        ["Event"]=>
        string(5) "Click"
        ["Date"]=>
        string(19) "2013-04-30 17:43:00"
        ["IPAddress"]=>
        string(12) "109.239.93.2"
        ["Detail"]=>
        string(60) "http://www.rbh.co.uk/rbhevent/?name=[fullname]&email=[email]"
      }
      [4]=>
      object(stdClass)#14 (4) {
        ["Event"]=>
        string(4) "Open"
        ["Date"]=>
        string(19) "2013-04-30 17:43:00"
        ["IPAddress"]=>
        string(12) "109.239.93.2"
        ["Detail"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
```

i am trying to count the events that are the same. So for example ["Event"] = Open =4 / ["Event"] = Click =1.

I am trying to achieve this via counting a foreach loop:

```
$i=0;
foreach($entry->Actions as $actions ) { 
echo $i++;          
}
```

Im not quite sure how to approach this? Can someone suggest a best practice?

Comment: Use an if statement in the loop?

Comment: Keep a map where each event value is the key and value is the count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$counts = array();

foreach($entry->Actions as $actions) {
    if(!isset($counts[$actions->Event])) {
        $counts[$actions->Event] = 0;
    }
    ++$counts[$actions->Event];
}

print_r($counts);
```

Comment: thanks! so when i echo $counts[$actions->Event]; i get the total for the ["Open"] value. How do i get the total for the ["Click"] value?

Comment: `$counts` is an array, so try echoing `$counts['Click']`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$amounts = array(); // Events as key
foreach($entry->Actions as $actions)
{
    if (isset($amounts[$actions["Event"]])) $amounts[$actions["Event"]]++;
    else $amounts[$actions["Event"]] = 1;
}
print_r($amounts);
echo "<br>".$amounts["Open"];
?>
```

Comment: I would offer a correction
    `if (isset($amounts[$actions["Event"]])) $amounts[$actions["Event"]]++; else $amounts[$actions["Event"]] = 1;`